# How should I receive this JSON data?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am a student currently studying Flutter and I want to receive this data,

so I am trying to keep trying, but I do not know how to receive it.

I'm still trying, but I'm not getting any progress. Please teach me.

```
 Future<UsedVacationsData> fetchUsedVacationsData(
      Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    Dio dio = await authDio();
    final response =
        await dio.get(API.usevacation_list, queryParameters: params);
    var result = json.decode(response.data);
    
    try {
      var usedVacationsData = UsedVacationsData(
        sid : result["data"]["sid"],
        period: result["data"]["period"],
        cnt: result["data"]["cnt"],
        name: result["data"]["name"],
        img_url: result["data"]["img_url"],
        use_day: result["data"]["use_day"],
        img_rm: result["data"]["img_rm"],
      );
      return usedVacationsData;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    throw new Exception('error getting vacations');
  }
method(repository)
```

object

```
success HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{
    "result": "SUCCESS",
    "message": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "0": {
                    "sid": "249",
                    "period": "2023.04.03",
                    "cnt": 0.5
            },
            "1": {
                    "sid": "249",
                    "period": "2023.04.05",
                    "cnt": 0.5
            },
            "name": "json",
            "img_url": "",
            "img_nm": "",
            "use_day": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Use entities, after you have created an Entity you can map your response and use the Entity object to get your data. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54704515/7149247

Comment: I think you should choose a simple API to learing, this API does not have a good struct for newbie in Flutter. But if you must be use this API, left the coment i will give you sample code to receive data.

Comment: @Xuân Cường I think I should use it because it's a project I'm collaborating on. Any help please?

Comment: Hi @sopu5555, after i check it again in your JSON , filed "Data" have no right struct, you need contact to backend config the JSON with Array inside the Data filed.

Answer (score 2):

Since `"data"` is a list, you should firstly specify the index of the value that you want to access.

```
result["data"][0]
```

another problem is since in the mentioned json example the `sid` value is inside another `Map` entry you should mention the parrent first.

```
result["data"][0]["0"]["sid"]
result["data"][0]["1"]["sid"]
```

Comment: [0] <- 
Is there any way to make this part a loop?

Comment: @sopu5555 You can use `result["data"].forEach((object) {})` or `result["data"].map((object) {})` or other approaches that suit the problem you want to solve

Answer (score 0):

Since "data" is a list of objects and contains only one object. you should specify the index number to access the object from the data list.

```
sid : result["data"][0]["0"]["sid"]
```

make these changes:

```
var usedVacationsData = UsedVacationsData(
        sid : result["data"][0]["0"]["sid"],
        period: result["data"][0]["0"]["period"],
        cnt: result["data"][0]["0"]["cnt"],
        name: result["data"][0]["name"],
        img_url: result["data"][0]["img_url"],
        use_day: result["data"][0]["use_day"],
        img_rm: result["data"][0]["img_rm"],
      );
```